# How can I write a Python script that uses some local credentials and make it secure?

Tags: python, security, encryption

I'm trying to write a Python script that logs into a website every 12hrs.

The problem is that it will not be hosted on my machine and I need to make the credentials secure. Nothing big, just secure enough so that the person opening the script will not see them hard coded in the script.

Should I use a compiled Python script or is there any way to provide the script with a encrypted file that has the credentials and only the script can read it?

Comment: This isn't possible. An isolated device that has both the key and ciphertext also has, by definition, the plaintext. Introduce an intermediary service, that you control, that can make requests on behalf of the Python script.

Comment: What _**Authentication**_ Possibilities does the _not be hosted on my machine_ Server offer?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily hide the credentials when you are going to take the credentials into a separate module and compile it using [cython](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#cython-hello-world). You just need to ship your script and the *.so file to the other machine.

cred.pyx:

```
def mysqlCredentials():
    return {'username': 'dbAdmin', 'password': 'mySecret'}


def someApiCredentials():
    return {'username': 'apiTestUser', 'password': '1234'}
```

You just need to compile it, as described in the cython tutorial and in your main script:

```
import cred

print (cred.__file__)
print(cred.mysqlCredentials())
```

Returns:

```
/tmp/cred.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
{'username': 'dbAdmin', 'password': 'mySecret'}
```

Comment: **Note:** The "hidden" credentials are visible in plain UTF-8 encoded binary in the resulting assembly, [as seen here](https://ibb.co/frd6jk).

Comment: Yes, you are right there is no absolute security without an intermediary service.

Comment: Your solution is likely adequate against "script kiddies" though.